# Boot-repair is asking for repositories

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I was trying to resize my Ubuntu partition from a kubuntu live usb and accidentally deleted the boot-bios partition. When Ubuntu wouldn't start, I just installed kubuntu. After using kubuntu for a while, I realized my nodejs website files were on the old partition. I tried to go into the home directory of the old partition with the file manager, but the root directory (which, I believe, is where the home directory is. Correct me if I'm wrong) is locked, so I can't access it. I used boot-repair and made a bios partition, but, when I apply the changes to grub's location in the program and click apply this message pops up:
Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software sources of Linux (sda6)
Sda6 is my os partition.
What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1) /home/user/ is the home folder.  /root is for root process to save files it uses  2) from software center you need to enable the repositories

Comment: that's weird. I can't find a home folder on the partition.

Comment: and i'm not sure how to enable repositories in kubuntu

Comment: ok. the kubuntu software center says all repositories are enabled.

Comment: open muon. in the upper right is a tab or button for setting repos